# Disabled product remains in catalog_category_product index (Magento Enterprise)

Tags: magento-enterprise, indexing, reindex

## The Setup

1. Magento EE 1.13
2. Product is within 1 or more categories and is enabled.
3. Product status is changed to disabled.
4. Product **still** appears on all category pages - the issue is that the product is still in the `catalog_category_product` index.

## The Problem

1. Unlike in CE where all indices can be rebuilt by the admin user, reindexing `catalog_category_product` manually is not possible in EE. Supposedly, `catalog_category_product` is (see below or [EE13 Reindexing](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee113-indexing)) to be reindexed when a product is updated, but this does not appear to be the case.
2. As a result, products that are disabled are not removed from catalog_category_product_index and these products continue to show up on the category pages.

### My Question

Is there anything that I can do via configuration or otherwise that will allow the client to reindex OR update the index when a product is disabled so that I don't run into this problem?  I see that you can schedule a reindex, but that only occurs once per day at most.

Obviously I can shell in and run `php -f indexer.php -- --reindex catalog_category_product` but this won't do for the average shop owner.

[image: What causes Reindexing]